# Where can one find how much memory is currently allocated to logbuffer?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, logging, memory

Do you know where it can be checked, how much memory is **currently** being used by the logbuffer?

```
some-switch#show log | i Buffer|Trap|udp
    Buffer logging:  level debugging, 2268 messages logged, xml disabled,
    Trap logging: level notifications, 1272 message lines logged
        Logging to xx.xx.xx.xx  (udp port 514,  audit disabled,
Log Buffer (50000 bytes):
```

I have trouble finding the exact process used for that:

```
some-switch#show processes memory sorted | inc log|Pool|Allo
Processor Pool Total:   73899224 Used:   28296368 Free:   45602856
      I/O Pool Total:   14680064 Used:   12240012 Free:    2440052
Driver te Pool Total:    1048576 Used:         40 Free:    1048536
 PID TTY  Allocated      Freed    Holding    Getbufs    Retbufs Process
 286   0     541580     525008      15608       4536          0 Syslog
 188   0        180        180       7052          0          0 REP Topology cha
 273   0          0          0       7052          0          0 Syslog Traps
   5   0    4277172   86430832       7052    2711884   53732884 Pool Manager
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you set the logging buffer size? If not, it is the default size, but we would need to know the specific device model and OS to tell you what the default size is.

Comment: I think my question was misunderstood here. The logging size was manually set (though not by me) to 50k bytes as can be seen from the output, but I'm asking about a command which would show me the exact current usage not the maximum cap size for the logbuffer.

Comment: The exact usage is the size to which it is set. The OS allocates that amount to the buffer, and nothing else will use that memory, except the buffer.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't expect that to be the case when the device wouldn't be generating that many logs so as to fill up the whole buffer. Anyway, shouldn't that memory allocation be also visible somewhere in the "show processes memory" output?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the wrong command. You show the *process* memory (`show processes`), not the *buffer* memory. Show the buffer memory with the `show memory` command. Something like:

```
show memory allocating-process | i logger
```

That command shows the logging buffer in my router. Notice that the buffer is allocated during router initialization.